# Kendo UI Update and create is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Reading rows is working fine in grid, but when updating and creating it is not working at all. It is not hitting the controller. I have provided the code, can you please look into what is wrong with the below code.

```
    The below json is return from the read webservice
    -------------------------------------------------

 {"items":[{"id":1,"publisherName":"Srini","active":false},  {"id":2,"publisherName":"Ram","active":false}]}


    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES -->
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery/plug-ins/colorbox-modal/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery/plug-ins/colorbox-modal/colorbox.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery/plug-ins/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery/plug-ins/jquery.jOrgchart.js"></script>      

    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-prettyCheckable.js"></script>    
    <script src="../bootstrap/plug-ins/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>   
    <script src="../bootstrap/plug-ins/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-downloadFile.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <!-- Kendo UI Web combined JavaScript -->
    <script src="../kendoUI/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>      



    <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script style="text/javascript">
        jq(document).ready(function () {
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            dataType: "json",
            transport: {
                read:  {
                     url:BASE_URL + "admin/searchPublishers.htm",
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false
                },
                update: {
                    url:BASE_URL + "admin/updatePublisher.htm",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: BASE_URL + "admin/createPublisher.htm",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        id: {
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        publisherName: {
                            type: "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                data: "items",
                total: "items.length" //total amount of records. This is needed for paging
            },
            pageSize: 20
        });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                   { field: "publisherName", title: "Publisher", width: "130px" },
                    { command: ["edit"], title: "Actions", width: "150px" }
               ],
            editable: "inline"
            });

        });
            </script>
        </div>


 Java Controller
 ---------------

    package com.wad.webui.controller;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

    import com.wad.core.model.lookup.PublisherLookupItem;

    /**
     * @author Srinivasa.K
     * 
     */
    @Controller
    public class PublisherController extends BaseController {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger
                .getLogger(PublisherController.class);

        private static final List<PublisherLookupItem> publishersList = new ArrayList<PublisherLookupItem>();

        static {
            PublisherLookupItem pb = new PublisherLookupItem();

            pb.setId(1);
            pb.setPublisherName("Srini");

            PublisherLookupItem pb1 = new PublisherLookupItem();

            pb1.setId(2);
            pb1.setPublisherName("Ram");

            publishersList.add(pb);
            publishersList.add(pb1);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/searchPublishers.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody
        JsonDataWrapper<PublisherLookupItem> searchPublishers(
                HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
            logger.debug("searchPublishers method ");

            JsonDataWrapper<PublisherLookupItem> result = new JsonDataWrapper<PublisherLookupItem>(
                    publishersList);

            return result;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/updatePublisher.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody
        PublisherLookupItem updatePublisher(
                @RequestBody PublisherLookupItem target, HttpServletRequest request)
                throws Exception {

            System.out.println("updatePublisher method :" + target);

            publishersList.add(target);
            return target;

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/createPublisher.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody
        PublisherLookupItem createPublisher(
                @RequestBody PublisherLookupItem target, HttpServletRequest request)
                throws Exception {

            System.out.println("createPublisher method :" + target);

            publishersList.add(target);
            return target;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Your Create and Update as Functions

```
create: function (options) {
   var newitem=[];
    newitem.push({
        id:options.data.id,
        publisherName:options.data.publisherName,
        active:false
     });
   $.ajax({
          url: BASE_URL + "admin/createPublisher.htm",
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST"
          cache: false,
          data:{target:Json.stringify(newitem)},
          success: function (result) {
                options.success(result); // Make sure to Return a Json back from the Server
          },
          error: function (result) {
                options.error(result);
           }
         });
},
update: function (options) {
  // do as the create 
},
```

From your Server Method createPublisher Return a Json Back

**Update** 
Define Your Schema Like this

```
schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    publisherName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                    active: { type: "boolean"}
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Hi, when try the alert(options.data.id); it is coming as undefined. and that is the reason newitem has only active:false. what should be done to resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you sure this is your Full Json result coming from searchPublishers . where is the "items" Property 

{"items":[{"id":1,"publisherName":"Srini","active":false},  {"id":2,"publisherName":"Ram","active":false}]}

Comment: Try my Update, define the Schema like that, also put this "console.log(JSON.stringify(options.data))" before the var newitem=[]; and let me know what you see in your console

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `schema.model.id` in your DataSource options.

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: {
            ...
```

The DataSource uses whatever field is set as the id to decide if the item is "new" or not. If the ID field is set tot he default value (undefined or 0) then it will send it to the server to be created. When there is no `schema.model.is` set, it basically disables creation.